Why did soldiers in the 18th century use massed volleys of musket fire?

Possible Duplicate: (7 answers)
Why do musketeers shoot in volley?

I had always thought that the massed musket volleys used in the French and Indian War and the American Revolution were employed to mitigate the inaccuracy of smoothbore muskets.
But recently a reenactor gave a different explanation.   Is it accurate?  I paraphrase:

militia men were devout Christians and followed the 10 Commandments, including though shalt not kill.  So they were not commanded to "aim" but rather to "present arms."  And they all fired at once.  If God decided their musket ball was supposed to take an enemy down, it was His will.  And no soldier would ever know if his ball was the one that caused a fatality.


You might want to see if Why do musketeers shoot in volley? answers your question. Bear in mind that not everyone in an army would have been devout Christians so that explanation wouldn't hold true everywhere.

Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence. Is there any evidence at all for this? If this had any merit, I would expect to find supporting material in training manuals, sermons, letters, biographies, etc.  In the absence of that evidence, I'm more inclined to accept the simpler solution.

@MCW I agree. We should also consider that religious command against crossbows were made during the Middle Ages, and never followed by contemporaries

I think S. Bird's point deserves some reinforcement. They weren't "Christians" - they were members of individual sects who disagreed with one another on nearly every interpretation of religious doctrine. The notion that they all agreed on this one principle is.... suspicious.

The musket was not the first weapon ever invented, and older means of waging war didn't take into account the wielder's moral qualms. Why did an 18th century militiaman's conscience matter more than an 8th century swordsman's, given the latter was a time when religion was far more important to everyday life? If your thesis was true, we would see tactics become less humane as the Modern Era replaced the Church with the State as the source of authority and proper conduct.

The reenactor explanation remember death sentenced: platoon committed to execute death penalty had one member loaded salvos, so to not bear the sin of killing to the member

Although there are problems with teh question, I'm reluctant to de-reference the two interesting answers.

A 2021 article by Bołdyre and Łopatecki shows that firing in volleys quickly became common practice across Eurasia in the sixteenth century wherever firearms were adopted--not just Christian Europe but also Turkey and Japan.
Given the time and physical menuvres involved in loading these weapons, coordinated volleys were a practical way to maintain relatively rapid pace of fire. One rank could kneel down or fall back to reload while allowing another rank with loaded weapons to aim and fire.
Perhaps the assertion in the question has some basis in how soldiers thought about what they were doing in particular times and places, but I see no direct evidence of it, and in any case it wasn't the actual reason that volley fire was standard practice.

The reason for using massed volleys instead of precision shots is widely documented, and several explanations stand out. I will list here some of them I have read about (please note that some might be mitigated by different historian's points of view):

Smoke created screens for the view, so that any precise shot was not doable after a few firings
Command and control by officers was better with a line of infantry men, thus it was preferred to keep them in line, giving efficiency to mass volleys
Cavalry would threaten, on the other hand, a group of dispersed men
Overall, the precision of each rifle was not controlled by industrial means, and was not good at distance, so individual firings could no get significant results



Question:
Why did soldiers in the 18th century use massed volleys of musket fire?

Short Answer:
It was a practice associated with muskets and the cult of offense, which ended as innovations such as the Minie Ball made riffles more effective by increasing their rate of fire to that of muskets.  The Riffles were more accurate with greater effective range which changed the way wars were fought eventually ending the practice of volley fire.
Answer:
It goes back to the cult of offense which prescribed that in the age of muskets the offense had such an advantage over any defensive measure it alone was the responsible way to conduct war.  All defensive measures taken to ensure the safety of your troops were self defeating because they deminished the unit's offensive capability.
To optimize one's offensive abilities was the key component of any successful commander.  In the 18th century this meant marching your men right up to the effective range of their weapons and altogether firing on one's enemy.  If you let the men determine when to fire some would fire to early effectively throwing away their shot, or perhaps worse some would fire too late.
Late was bad because a good percentage of soldiers would be dead after receiving the enemy's volley.  So late shots had a high likelihood of never being fired.   When to fire thus became the purview of the officer trusted to make the call for the entire line.  This practice ended when accuracy improved around the time Crimean War.
Rifles provided greater accuracy and had been around since the 15th century.  The problem was their loading speed was quite slow because the round had to be jammed down the barrel of the chamber snuggly to take advantage of the grooves in the barrel of the gun which gave the round accuracy at range.  This could take minutes on the battle field as the black powder residue would build up inside the barrel of the riffle.  Muskets  could sustain an effective rate of fire 2-3 rounds a minute.  Riffles couldn't compete.
Smooth bore muskets were preferred for their faster rate of fire.
This changed when the Minié ball in the mid 1800's gave the riffle the ability to load just as fast as the musket.  The round no longer had to fit snuggle to the barrel.  The Minie round would expand upon firing so one would load it easier and not sacrifice accuracy.  These rounds began to see some limited use in the Crimean War and more in the later American Civil War and began to end the practice of volley fire.
While volley fire was still practiced, its role diminished with the advent of rifled weapons and the Minié ball. Instead of relying on massed volleys to create a “wall of lead” at close range, soldiers could now pick targets individually at longer ranges. This increased the effectiveness of fire but made traditional volley fire less necessary.

Downvote. Google Battle of Fontenoy, and the gyrations employed by both French and British to goad the other into firing first; believing strongly that having the second volley (and option to instead charge with bayonet and loaded musket) was a potentially overpowering advantage. This entire answer is basically speculative analysis - and I've learned that to be a very unsound foundation for analyzing warfare of the period. Research every assumption you make of the period.

While it is true that musketry was frequently very inaccurate, even over extended periods of time - there are also instances (such as some of Wellington's Peninsular battles, as well as the Old Guard at Aspern-Essling) where it was extremely effecitve even over long periods of time, when the smoke had more than enough time to collect and block vision. We don;t know enough about why and how both situations could occur at different times.

@PieterGeerkens if you assertion is accurate it would be an exception and therefore not relevant.  Obviously those who take a volley first will have fewer soldiers to return fire.  The objective of volley fire was not just to fire first but to do so in the effective range of the weapons used.

You don't get it: firing first was a morale failure. "Wait until you see the whites of their eyes" was effective because volley fire was much more effective at shorter ranges; and most importantly at the specific range for which you were trained to level your musket for. Volley were not aimed fire, but rather "leveled" fire (ie designed to be effective at a specific, and constant, pre-decided range) - and deadly effective at the specific narrow range around that which your "leveling" was designed for, and otherwise not very effective.

The only source this cites is the Wikipedia article for Minie balls, which did not exist in the 18th century and are irrelevant to the question. The cult of the offensive is also a 19th century concept and is strategic rather than tactical in nature. This + a clear misunderstanding of the amount of casualties a volley at a distance actually inflicted = a downvote.

@spavel I attempted to explain why volley shot came about under muskets, given the limitations of the more accurate and longer ranged riffles,  yet still the desire to maximize offense in the battle.   Then what ended the practice of volley shot, the Minie ball which addressed the short comings of riffles ( rate of fire ).
